# Find the comment's post title

Tags: wordpress, comments

I am trying to create a plugin what will be a sime kind of a comments archive.
I have looked at [`get_comment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment).

I am looking to show where the comment came from, specifically the title of the post where the comment is attached. This is part of my code:

```
if ( $comments ) {
  foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    // here you can display the comment in the way you want

    echo 'from: ' . $comment->i want comment post title here . '<br/>';
    echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
  }
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
<?php
    if ( $comments )
        foreach($comments as $comment){
            // here you can display the comment in the way you want

            echo 'from: ' . get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '<br/>';
            echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>;
        }
?>
```